# How to create a polymorphic unboxed array within ST monad?

Tags: haskell

This code compiles with no problem:

```
import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import Data.Array.MArray (MArray)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray)
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray, newArray, STUArray)

new :: Double -> UArray Int Double
new a = runSTUArray (newArray (0, 9) a)
```

But, this:

```
new :: e -> UArray Int e
new a = runSTUArray (newArray (0, 9) a)
```

fails as one would expect, with error:

```
No instance for (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s))
  arising from a use of ‘newArray’
In the first argument of ‘runSTUArray’, namely
  ‘(newArray (0, 9) a)’
In the expression: runSTUArray (newArray (0, 9) a)
In an equation for ‘new’: new a = runSTUArray (newArray (0, 9) a)
```

However, adding the type-class constraint would not help, as changing the type signature to

```
new :: (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) => e -> UArray Int e
```

would still fail with

```
Could not deduce (MArray (STUArray s0) e (ST s0))
from the context (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s))
  bound by the type signature for
             new :: MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s) => e -> UArray Int e
  at pilot.hs:7:8-58
The type variable ‘s0’ is ambiguous
In the ambiguity check for the type signature for ‘new’:
  new :: forall e s.
         MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s) =>
         e -> UArray Int e
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for ‘new’:
  new :: (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) => e -> UArray Int e
```

any way to make this work?

---

EDIT: Found out this has already been discussed on [Haskell](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-August/016338.html) and [Haskell-Cafe](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2004-July/006400.html) mailing list, with this minimal solution taken from [here](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-August/016354.html):

```
-- https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2005-August/016354.html
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import Data.Array.MArray (MArray)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray, Ix)
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray, newArray, STUArray)

new :: UArrayElement e => e -> UArray Int e
new a = case freezer of
    Freezer runSTUArray' -> runSTUArray' $ (newArray (0, 9) a)

data Freezer i e = Freezer
    ((forall s. MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s) => ST s (STUArray s i e))
    -> UArray i e)

class UArrayElement e where
    freezer :: Ix i => Freezer i e

instance UArrayElement Bool    where freezer = Freezer runSTUArray
instance UArrayElement Char    where freezer = Freezer runSTUArray
instance UArrayElement Double  where freezer = Freezer runSTUArray
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is just not possible, because `Array` has no explicit class for unboxable types. [`Vector` has](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html).

Comment: @leftaroundabout my use-case involves 2-dimensional indexing, which is clumsy with vectors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following seems to work. I don't know if it can be minimized. One downside is that you will need to add an instance of `Unboxable` for each `MArray` instance that you'll want to be able to use -- but at least thanks to `DefaultSignatures` you don't have to write any actual code. I've included an instance for `Int` to show what I mean.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.ST

class Unboxable e where
    unboxable :: Dict (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s))
    default unboxable :: MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s) => Dict (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s))
    unboxable = Dict

new :: forall e. Unboxable e => e -> UArray Int e
new e = runSTUArray build where
    build :: forall s. ST s (STUArray s Int e)
    build = case unboxable :: Dict (MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s)) of
        Dict -> newArray (0, 9) e

instance Unboxable Int
```

The `Dict` type comes from Edward Kmett's [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package.

Answer (score 5):

As a refinement to Daniel Wagner's answer, given that we're already using [`constraints`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) we can make use of `Data.Constraint.Forall` to get all the `Unboxable` instances in one fell swoop:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  ScopedTypeVariables, TypeOperators,
  MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts,
  FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import Data.Array.MArray (MArray)
import Data.Array.Unboxed (UArray)
import Data.Array.ST (runSTUArray, newArray, STUArray)

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Forall

class MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s) => Unboxable e s
instance MArray (STUArray s) e (ST s) => Unboxable e s

new :: forall e. Forall (Unboxable e) => e -> UArray Int e
new a = runSTUArray build where
  build :: forall s. ST s (STUArray s Int e)
  build = case inst :: Forall (Unboxable e) :- Unboxable e s of
    Sub Dict -> newArray (0, 9) a

-- can be specialized to Double
new' :: Double -> UArray Int Double
new' = new
```

Comment: I guess I'm obligated to point out that [`Forall` is unsound](https://github.com/ekmett/constraints/issues/11) and will be restricted greatly in the next version of `constraints`, probably to the point where it can no longer be used to avoid the individual instances.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, is `Forall` unsound with neither of the dubious features of overlapping instances and closed type families?

Comment: @dfeuer [Open type families are enough](http://oerjan.nvg.org/haskell/Forall/UC3.hs).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I sure wish I could understand how that all works. Brilliant and horrifying. Thanks.

Comment: @dfeuer As far as I can see, `Forall` is implemented by checking that a constraint is satisfied by two non-exported types `A,B`, the idea being that the only way you can make your class to be instantiated on those non-accessible types is to use a universal instance, so `unsafeCoerce` should be OK. Alas, type families can be used to write `F x y z = Bool` when any two of `x,y,z` are equal and `= Int` otherwise. However, from the `Forall` implementation, `F` is always `Bool` (it should have checked with `A,B,C` instead of `A,B`). From this, you can reach unsoundness.

Comment: @dfeuer So, in short, you can't safely use a bounded set of skolem constants. Orjan made even a worse example, you can write (paraphrased) `data C; type family F where F t C = Int ; F t x = Bool` which, no matter how many skolem constants you use, you can't detect it is not constantly `Bool`. I fear that having if-then-else on equality at the type level breaks a kind of parametricitly which `Forall` conveniently relied upon.

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out this issue! It seems that we would need a true skolem variable (such that it's not equal or inequal to any monotype) for this to work... I'm wondering though whether we can emulate a true skolem, after all, true skolems often clog up closed type family reduction during type checking - maybe we can introduce "clogging up" artificially?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I looked at your code and ... I don't understand why that compiles without `OverlappingInstances`. The type family cases overlap, no?

Comment: @dfeuer: the implicit equalities between the params differentiate the instance heads. It's arguably a dodgy feature, and probably it'd be better to banish equalities to instance constraints.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, the dodgy bit is that they overlap. `Blah x x y` obviously overlaps `Blah x y y`. I would therefore hope and expect that GHC would require `OverlappingInstances` to allow that.

Comment: @dfeuer: open type family instances [can overlap](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html#type-family-overlap) if they have the same result type under their unifying substitution.

Comment: BTW I conjured up an [alternative `Forall`](https://github.com/ekmett/constraints/issues/11) definition that prevents Ørjan's unsound programs from checking and is still usable in this case. I'm not sure if it's waterproof, so you might want to give it a look.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Darn, would you believe I got essentially *just* the same idea yesterday... BTW my version of it also rejects my unsound programs, but for two of them it rejects them with a spurious "superclass cycle" message, which could be annoying when using it otherwise. I should test if yours does...

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: yep, my version also does the "superclass cycle" thing... The question is whether it ever comes up with code that doesn't actively tries to subvert the system.

Comment: [My version](http://oerjan.nvg.org/haskell/Forall/NewForall.hs), also I made some [test cases](http://oerjan.nvg.org/haskell/Forall/TestNewForall.hs), look in particular at the commented out `H1` declaration, which fails for this reason and which I imagine is similar to something people might want to use in practice. It seems to require a type equality somewhere, note how the otherwise similar `Monoid2` just works.

Comment: And I've continued this on the [GitHub issue page](https://github.com/ekmett/constraints/issues/11), as well as filed a [GHC bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11067).

Comment: @dfeuer Perhaps you'd like to know that AndrásKovács managed to work around that remaining bug. So with any luck `Data.Constraint.Forall` might be repaired without limiting the API (even generalizing it to become polykinded!)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, yes, I'm following the GitHub issue. I just hope the new version doesn't fall to some other clever trick. What makes you two think it's safer, exactly?

Comment: @dfeuer (1) When I started university, one of the first math library books I got hold of was Bourbaki's Set Theory. I remember only *one* particular thing from that book, namely the weird way it defined quantification. It was essentially like this. (2) With open type families, when an instance isn't defined, GHC can make no assumptions about the resulting type, because it could be defined any way whatsoever in another module. So everything it *does* deduce must hold for all the types. (Now handwave that GHC won't care if it's actually non-exported or closed.) (3) You can never be sure.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, the only potentially scary bit is that I believe it does know that `F a ~ F a` even when `F a` gets stuck; I don't see a way to exploit that, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. If it works, though, it's an excellent fix.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes it does know that, and I think it would be bad if it *didn't*. I even made a test case for it (`funEq2`) because I was unsure about it.